# How to write SoapClient request which has basic auth in it?

Tags: 8

Actually I need to implement SoapClient in Drupal 8. Following XML is Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://www.example.com/common/ServiceRequestHeader_v1_0/types" xmlns:typ1="http://www.example.com/customer/CustomerViewRequest_v1_0/types">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <typ:serviceRequestHeader>
         <applicationCredential>
            <ID>USERNAME</ID>
            <credential>*****</credential>
         </applicationCredential>
         <transactionModel>
            <synchronousRequest>true</synchronousRequest>
         </transactionModel>
         <userCredential>
            <ID>RITESH</ID>
         </userCredential>
      </typ:serviceRequestHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ1:serviceRequest>
         <requestPreamble>
            <companyCode>IN</companyCode>
            <customerNumber>12345678</customerNumber>
         </requestPreamble>
      </typ1:serviceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried following code for the same but it is failing and I am not able to make any progress on this:

```
    $client = new SoapClient('https://example.com:9043/CustomerView_v1_0_vs0',
    array(
        // Stuff for development.
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,

        // Auth credentials for the SOAP request.
        'ID' => 'USERNAME',
        'credential' => 'Password',


    )
);
    dump($client); die;
```

Its giving below error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn&#039;t load
```

Can anyone suggest some way on this ?

Comment: You have to send he auth as a header

Comment: This has more to do with SoapClient than Drupal. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is nearly there for you, but ID and credential are the wrong keys in the options array.

```
       'login' => 'USERNAME',
       'password' => 'Password',
```

I suggest that you put the username and password into conf in your settings.php file so they are not in your codebase nor your site configuration data. See [How secure are variable_get and variable_set?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38140/how-secure-are-variable-get-and-variable-set) for details on how to securely have credentials in Drupal's config system.